# indian rupee symbol not visible on system view,it displayed on mobiles

Tags: wordpress

Event booking pro wp plugin is not displaying Indian rupee symbol on desktop view and it is working ok in mobile view. Is there any method to display on desktop view.
How it could be made visible on both mobile and desktop view.

Comment: provide link of that page so I can guess is it css issue or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's due to the browser.

The new Rupee symbol can be rendered directly in html like this ₹. Type `&#8377;` in your code source.